# On click of label add class to previous div, just not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a class to a div (.checkbox) when clicking on the label that follows from it. It doesn't seem to be working at all though and I don't know why.

Below is the javascript and the basic form layout that I have set up.

**JS**

```
$('#filter ul label').click(function() {

    if ($(this).prev('.checkbox').hasClass('checked')) {
      $(this).prev('.checkbox').removeClass('checked');
    } else {
      $(this).prev('.checkbox').addClass('checked');
    }

});
```

**HTML**

```
      <form id="filter">
        <div>
          <a href="#">Service <span>&#xE805;</span></a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div class="checkbox"></div>
              <label for="new-build">
                <input type="checkbox" name="new-build" id="new-build">
                New Build
              </label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="checkbox"></div>
              <label for="extensions">
                <input type="checkbox" name="extensions" id="extensions">
                Extensions
              </label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="checkbox"></div>
              <label for="refurbishments">
                <input type="checkbox" name="refurbishments" id="refurbishments">
                Refurbishments
              </label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="checkbox"></div>
              <label for="fit-out">
                <input type="checkbox" name="fit-out" id="fit-out">
                Fit Out
              </label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="checkbox"></div>
              <label for="maintenance">
                <input type="checkbox" name="maintenance" id="maintenance">
                Maintenance
              </label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="checkbox"></div>
              <label for="design-build">
                <input type="checkbox" name="design-build" id="design-build">
                Design &amp; Build
              </label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="checkbox"></div>
              <label for="listed-building">
                <input type="checkbox" name="listed-building" id="listed-building">
                Fit Out
              </label>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <input type="submit">
      </form>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm assuming it is something really simple that I'm missing completely.

Thank you.

Comment: *WHAT* exactly does not work?

Comment: can be achieved with a bit less code, see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution works perfectly fine. Please make sure that you included jQuery and put your javascript in a

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

block.

---

It seems like the `click` event is not fired when writing the markup like you did. You can bind your function to the `change` event of the checkbox instead. This should work as expected:

```
$('#filter input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
    var $div = $(this).parent().prev('.checkbox');
    if ($div.hasClass('checked')) {
      $div.removeClass('checked');
    } else {
      $div.addClass('checked');
    }
});
```

Check Fiddle for demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g3v4F/3/

Comment: .parent() would select the parent of the label which is a <li> element. He wants to select the previous <div>.

Comment: Sorry, it is within the document.ready, I forgot to include this.
**edit** No it's bloody not!!! Thanks for your help

Comment: @Merguez But your example isn't working anyway? Clicking the label doesn't add a `checked` class to the div element?

Comment: Yes it does, check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g3v4F/2/ Edit: ahhh clicking the label is the issue, sorry sorry i'll look into that.

Comment: @Niklas thanks for pointing out the issue, i updated the answer to a working example.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
 $('#filter ul label').click(function() {
     var $cb = $(this).prev('.checkbox');
     $cb.toggleClass('checked', !$cb.hasClass('checked'));
 });
```

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8eQAR/)

JS should be either below your HTML or wrapped in document.ready

```
$(function(){
    // your JS here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a problem with the order of code. At the time your JavaScript code is executed the DOM elements are not there because they come after the JS.

Move the JS behind the HTML or use the `jQuery(document). ready(function () {...})` construct (recommended).

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: I knew I'd forgotten something. Thank you for the response.

Comment: By the way. I don't think you want to set the class according to the class name of that div, but to the checked state of the checkbox. Your if  statement should check for `'is:checked'` of the checkbox element.

Comment: That is a good call actually, at least this way it will remain accurate. Thank you.

Comment: Additionally you want the changed event of the checkbox not the click of the label. You could focus the checkbox with tab key and toggle checkbox with space key. By only using clock you'll miss that. http://api.jquery.com/change/